# Vote counts >= 100 for linked questions do not wrap properly

Tags: bug, design, related-questions, linked-questions

On some SE sites, the vote counts for linked and related questions get wrapped. I cannot remember seeing it before.

Not affected are Stack Overflow and Server Fault. Affected are:

Askubuntu:

[image: askubuntu linked question]

Sec.SE ([report on meta.Sec.SE](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1533/2630)):

[image: Sec.Se linked/related questions]

Browser: Firefox 28 on Arch Linux.

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox Aurora 30.0a2 and Chrome 34 ([example question where it'll show up](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55523/check-logs-for-heartbleed-exploit-use))

Comment: It happens on meta.SE as well. Check out the related section in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230185/what-to-do-with-offtopic-answers-post-split).