# What to do with post-split-offtopic answers to ontopic questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, scope, mso-mse-split

Many answers to still on-topic questions (i.e. about SE besides SO) are offtopic now (after the split) as they express SO-centric positions. What should we do about them; flag and delete? Flag the whole question for migration to MSO and repost on MSE?

Comment: @MartijnPieters You can't close answers; my concern are questions that *seem* answered but are not for the network in general in case the answer(s) only apply to [SO].

Comment: Ah, you are talking about *answers*. Roight. Downvote?

Comment: Please don't down-vote them, they're still voicing opinions about things _as it relates to their site_, which is perfectly fine here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answers presenting the point-of-view of a particular network site doesn't mean it is providing an off-topic answer. And, Stack Overflow is still very much a part of the Stack Exchange Network - it  has just received its own child meta.

You are still very much welcome to post an answer on MSE showing how that would affect a particular site (which would naturally be also applicable for some of the other network sites where you don't participate).

Moreover, most of the answers which are written to present the views from the angle of Stack Overflow should be also applicable for other sites — otherwise, someone would have commented or given an answer to present the view from other angles by now. If you believe that is not the case, put a bounty to have more discussion on the question.

And, don't flag to delete the answers giving views specific to a particular network site!

Comment: This ^^^^ - exactly this.